# Socket emmission mysteriously does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, socket.io

I'm coding a game in Node.js with Socket.IO and I'm using back and forth emissions to transfer data between client and host. It hasn't been to hard to learn, but this is stumping me to no end. I am making a game that uses rooms, the players type in a room code and join it then I'm emitting game specific data to that room.

Here is a method that works

```
    /**
     *  The amount of time to answer the questions is over
     *  @param data - room number
     */
    socket.on('timesUp', function (data) {

        console.log("Times UP!");

        console.log(data.roomNum);

        socket.emit('startVoting');


    })
```

This is the code that is not working:

```
socket.on('playersVote', function (data) {

        console.log("playersVote data: " + data.playerOneResponse);

        console.log(data.roomNum);

        socket.to(data.roomNum).emit('playerStartVoting', {pOne: data.playerOneResponse, pTwo: data.playerTwoResponse} );

        console.log("after io emission");

    })
```

I know that the emission is making it to the server because all of the console logs print meaningful data:

```
playersVote data: [object Object]
{
  question: null,
  response: 'c',
  name: 'w',
  id: 'TW_92Ojct1EyhhE5AAAL',
  roomNum: '845'
}
845
after io emission
```

The handler on the app side for the 'playerStartVoting' emissions is as follows:

`IO.socket.on('playerStartVoting', IO.onPlayerStartVoting);`

Which calls `onPlayerStartVoting` which is :

```
        onPlayerStartVoting: function (data) {

            console.log("voting started");

            if (data.pOne.id === App.mySocketID || data.pTwo.id === App.mySocketID) {
                App.Player.displayBlank();
            }
            else {
                App.Player.vote(data);
            }
        },
```

I have never been able to get the client to console log "voting started" so I know this is where it dies. What I cannot figure out is why this is happening.

Hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the problem ended up being is that I wasn't emitting the roomNum with a .toString() method. Adding the .toString() to the end of my roomNum variable made it work